# install python module using a zip file

Tags: python, module, pip

I have downloaded a zip file from [here](https://github.com/sobhe/hazm/archive/master.zip) but I don't know how to install it and then use it in my python 2.7 
they said it supports both python 2 and 3

using command: "pip install hazm" after bunch of lines it gets to these errors:

```
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libwapiti\src
C:\Users\Mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Pyt
hon\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Icwapiti/src -
Ilibwapiti -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tccwapiti/src/bcd.c /Fobuild\
temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\cwapiti/src/bcd.obj -std=c99
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c99'
bcd.c
cwapiti/src/bcd.c(30) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdboo
l.h': No such file or directory
error: command '"C:\Users\Mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\V
isual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:
\\users\\mohammad\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-y3whx6\\libwapiti\\setup.py';
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\
n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\mohammad\appdata\local\temp\p
ip-m_wrwt-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compil
e" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\mohammad\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-y3
whx6\libwapiti
```

and when I use command:"python ./setup.py" these errors show up:

```
C:\Users\Mohammad\Desktop\Term 6\AI\AI Project\OPERATE\hazm-master\hazm-master>p
ython ./setup.py
C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
'install_requires'
 warnings.warn(msg)
 usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
 or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
 or: setup.py --help-commands
 or: setup.py cmd --help

 error: no commands supplied
```

Comment: also I get an error using "pip install hazm"

Comment: "I get an error" doesn't help anyone solve your problem. Show us what you tried and what happened. (Because `pip install hazm` is the right answer, as [the project's readme](https://github.com/sobhe/hazm/) explicitly says.)

Comment: @abarnert i added the errors i get using that command

Comment: Your question title attracts views, but you selected an answer that solved your specific problem without answering the question in the title. Please consider marking the popular, direct answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package is on PyPI, so all you have to do is run the following command:

```
pip install hazm
pip2 install hazm #Explicit python 2 selection
pip3 install hazm #Explicit python 3 selection
```

If you really want to use that file, you have to run the `setup.py` file, you can do this using the following command (assuming you are in the hazm-master folder):

```
python ./setup.py
python2 ./setup.py #Explicit python 2 selection
python3 ./setup.py #Explicit python 3 selection
```

Comment: You don't have to run `setup.py` to use that file. `pip` has been able to install from directories since way back in the 0.x days, and it's been able to install from zip archives since… I think 1.5.

Comment: This answer doesn't match the question title, so it may have been good for OP but is bad for future readers

Answer (score 59):

The right way to install a zipfile (at least if it's properly designed, but I just tested this one, and it is) is with `pip`:

```
pip install hazm-master.zip
```

Or, if you prefer, you can unzip it and use `pip` from within the directory:

```
unzip hazm-master.zip
cd hazm-master
pip install .
```

But neither of these is really necessary, because, as [the project's readme](https://github.com/sobhe/hazm/) says, you don't need to download it manually; just do:

```
pip install hazm
```

Comment: On a machine with no internet access, installing from a zip can be necessary! Download zip to other machine, transfer it to blocked machine, and install.

Comment: You can even use to directly download and install a zip online. I wanted to install the big-O module from github and all I had to do was `pip install https://github.com/pberkes/big_O/archive/v0.9.zip`

Comment: On a machine with no admin rights, you will also need to `pip install --user fname.zip` . Find the resulting site-packages under AppData\Roaming when you are using MS

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, `hazm 0.5` uses `libwapiti` for its *POS Tagger* class and I'd the exact same related problem installing `hazm` over Windows 7. For Python 2.7, you've got to use ***MS VC++ 2008 (a.k.a 9.00) for Python 2.7*** (available on Microsoft's site) for some packages including `hazm`. But the pain won't be finished here! MSVC9 does not have some C++ header files like stdbool.h and a few others which you've got to create or copy-paste manually in MSVC installition folder.
If you want to use hazm 0.5, the best you can do is to install and use it on Linux:

```
sudo pip install hazm
```

or

```
sudo pip3 install hazm
```

But if you need to use it under Windows OS you can use `hazm 0.4` which does not need the troublesome `libwapiti` module as recommanded by hazm's creator:

```
pip install hazm==0.4
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to install `hazm`, you need to install all of its prerequisites.

If you install it with `pip install hazm` or `pip install hazm-master.zip`, `pip` will try to fetch and install all of them for you. If you unzip it and run `setup.py` manually, you have to take care of figuring out and installing all the prerequisites on your own (and possibly telling `hazm` how to find them); that isn't going to solve anything.

Your problem appears to be with [`libwapiti`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libwapiti/), which requires a C compiler, and presumably also the [`Wapiti`](https://wapiti.limsi.fr/#download) C library. I'm not actually sure that `Wapiti` and `libwapiti` actually work natively on Windows at all. Maybe they do, but if not, all you can do is port them yourself, file a feature request on their issue trackers, or use Cygwin instead of native Windows.

At any rate, *if* they support Windows, what you need to do should be:

- Download, make, and install `Wapiti` (see the link above, and read the instructions on their website or inside the package).
- `pip install hazm` again.

Answer (score 1):

I checked libwapiti and it seems to be working just on linux. because of that i couden't install hazm on windows. at last i could install hazm on linux.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience - after several times that I'd to reinstall Windows/Ubuntu and so Python and its packages including `hazm`, I'd avoid going for its new version due some of its prerequisites which made me several problems before I figure them out. For Ubuntu it was okay but for Windows I couldn't collect and setup all prerequisites like `wapiti` and `libwapiti`. I suggest installing and using hazm 0.4 or 0.3. Not every update makes life easier, believe me!