# Install hazm on anaconda 3

Tags: python, anaconda

i want to install [hazm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hazm/0.4) on anaconda3 .I use this command to install this package with downloaded package  :

```
 conda install hazm-0.4.tar.gz
```

or this command in pycharm :

```
conda install hazm
```

in both manner it gives me this error:

> Solving environment: failed
>
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
>   current channels:
>
> - hazm
>
> Current channels:
>
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instruction on the [hazm documentation page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hazm/0.4) is to install the package using `pip`:

```
pip install hazm
```

`pip` can be used to [install non-conda packages in a conda environment](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-non-conda-packages), if there isn't a conda package available.

Reading [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148335/install-python-module-using-a-zip-file) it sounds as if the latest version of `hazm` may not install under Windows because of a dependency issue. If you're on Windows you need to specify the 0.4 version, either with `hazm==0.4` or simply by pointing to the archive you downloaded. I was able to install `hazm` 0.4 from the gz archive on Anaconda under Windows without errors as follows:

```
conda create -n testhazm python=3.4 nltk=3.0.0
activate testhazm
pip install hazm-0.4.tar.gz
```

(If I allowed `conda` to use the latest version of `nltk`, the installation went OK but I got an error when I actually started Python and tried to import `hazm`. You may be able to get it working with a more recent version of `nltk` and/or Python by experimenting.)

**Background:**

When you do `conda install hazm` the error message `The following packages are not available from current channels: hazm` means exactly what it says: the channels specified in your current conda configuration do not contain this package.

Often, packages that are not available on the default conda channels can be found on `conda-forge`, but I checked this with `conda search hazm -c conda-forge` and it looks like it's not there either.

To use the command `conda install hazm-0.4.tar.gz`, the downloaded file would need to be a conda package, not just a Python module.

Comment: yes i want to use hazm in python 3.6 and this command 'pip install hazm' install it on python 2.7

Comment: is there anyway to add not conda package on conda env?