# pytube HTTP Not found

Tags: python, pytube

I am getting this error `HTTP Error 404: Not Found` when I run this code :

```
from pytube import YouTube 

url = input("Paste URL:")
urll = YouTube(url)

choose = input('Choose: 4K , FHD , HD , 480p')
def D4k():
   if choose == '4K' :
      urll.streams.get_by_itag(313).downlaod()

print(D4k())
```

I found on internet many solutions like upgrading pytube or installing it again, but I tried that and I am using the latest version of it which is : 10.9.3 . Could anyone help me? and is there a way to stop getting this error even if its resolved.

Comment: What is the url

Comment: I guess the URL you're pasting is not correct, but what is it?

Comment: this is the url : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9jZ01i92JI8&ab_channel=FilmHD60FPS

Answer (score 0):

Try using this syntax.

```
from pytube import YouTube
YouTube('link').streams.first().download()
yt = YouTube('link')
yt.streams
```

Comment: it didn't work, however this is not how I want the code to be , I don't know why they don't just fix this problem for ever

Answer (score 0):

Presently pytube Module is having error on downloading videos.
Fix shall be in place soon.

Refer this to tweak your code.
[get_video_info YouTube endpoint suddenly returning 404 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67615278/get-video-info-youtube-endpoint-suddenly-returning-404-not-found/68562449#68562449)

For a proper fix you can try below fix
https://github.com/Zeecka/pytube/tree/fix_1060

Comment: But can you explain more what to do with the second link? I downloaded the .zip file where should I extract it? . Thank you

Comment: @LastFox Run this  `pip install pkgname.zip` [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148335/install-python-module-using-a-zip-file)