# I cant install module mailer

Tags: python

it gives this error:

```
  Downloading mailer-0.8.1.zip (6.5 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in mailer setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

i tried upgrading pip and restarting my computer and completly uninstall python and dosent work
if no one can find a way to install can someone give me an idea of how i can send emails with my python script?

Comment: Standard build-in smtplib perhaps?

Comment: Please try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148335/install-python-module-using-a-zip-file) after downloading zip file from pypi for the mailer module